# Flutter Positioning Stack Complex Design

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am struggling with this, How Can I achieve this design? My code included stack widget with container background image but it's not showing properly.

[image]

I tried and it's showing like bellow image,

[image]

I want to design exactly like first image, I am stucking on positioning of small camera icon, background image, buy now banner etc, here's my code-

```
Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
//                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: new AssetImage(
                            'images/icons/egle2.png',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 100,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
//                                    right: 1.0,
                                    child: Material(
                                      elevation: 8.0,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                        maxRadius: 50,
                                        minRadius: 40,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                            'images/icons/jully.png'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
//                                  SizedBox(
//                                    width: 20,
//                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: 0.0,
                                    top: 0.0,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        'images/icons/camera.png',
//              height: ,
//              width: 25,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Jully',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: null,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  height: 25,
//                      width: 30,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: UniversalVariables.yellowColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.card_giftcard,
                                        size: 15,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 2,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'ID: 123875',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 200,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                children: [

                                  Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 100,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: 1.0,
                                    child: Material(
                                      elevation: 8.0,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                        maxRadius: 50,
                                        minRadius: 40,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        backgroundImage:
                                        AssetImage('images/icons/king.png'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: 0.0,
                                    top: 0.0,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        'images/icons/camera.png',
//              height: ,
//              width: 25,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'King_20',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: null,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  height: 25,
//                      width: 30,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: UniversalVariables.yellowColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.card_giftcard,
                                        size: 15,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 2,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'ID: 123875',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 100,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: 1.0,
                                    child: Material(
                                      elevation: 8.0,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                        maxRadius: 50,
                                        minRadius: 40,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        backgroundImage:
                                        AssetImage('images/icons/hulk.png'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
//          top: 5.0,
                                    right: 0.0,
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        'images/icons/camera.png',
//              height: ,
//              width: 25,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Hulk',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: null,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  height: 25,
//                      width: 30,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: UniversalVariables.yellowColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.card_giftcard,
                                        size: 15,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 2,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'ID: 123875',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 200,
                              ),
//                              Stack(
//                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
//                                children: [
//                                  Container(
//                                    height: 100,
//                                    width: 100,
//                                  ),
//                                  Positioned(
//                                    right: 1.0,
//                                    child: Material(
//                                      elevation: 8.0,
//                                      color: Colors.blue,
//                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
//                                      child: CircleAvatar(
//                                        maxRadius: 50,
//                                        minRadius: 40,
//                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
//                                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
//                                            'images/icons/happyman.png'),
//                                      ),
//                                    ),
//                                  ),
//                                  SizedBox(
//                                    width: 20,
//                                  ),
//                                  Positioned(
////          top: 5.0,
//                                    right: 0.0,
//                                    child: Container(
//                                      child: Image.asset(
//                                        'images/icons/camera.png',
////              height: ,
////              width: 25,
//                                      ),
//                                    ),
//                                  ),
//                                ],
//                              ),
//                              SizedBox(
//                                height: 5,
//                              ),
//                              Text(
//                                'Happy Man',
//                                style: TextStyle(
//                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
//                              ),
//                              SizedBox(
//                                height: 5,
//                              ),
//                              GestureDetector(
//                                onTap: null,
//                                child: Container(
//                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
//                                  height: 25,
////                      width: 30,
//                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
//                                    color: UniversalVariables.yellowColor,
//                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
//                                  ),
//                                  child: Row(
//                                    children: [
//                                      Icon(
//                                        Icons.card_giftcard,
//                                        size: 15,
//                                      ),
//                                      SizedBox(
//                                        width: 2,
//                                      ),
//                                      Text(
//                                        'ID: 123875',
//                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
//                                      ),
//                                    ],
//                                  ),
//                                ),
//                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      top: 280,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset('images/icons/badge4.png',),
                                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                    Text(
                                      "X 70 = \$10",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: null,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                  height: 35,
//                      width: 30,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: UniversalVariables.blackColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Buy Now',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Do you want the whole widget to be responsive or the height needs to be fixed while width is device dependent?

Comment: Actually whole widget

Answer (score 0):

As usual, there might be better examples on how to achieve this result.
Here's a fast attempt to recreate it. It needs some fine tuning to fit any screen size, using AutoSizeText and rewriting PersonDrawer to be responsive too.
But I hope that it will help you to move in the right direction.

```dart
class MySuperCoolStackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double baseWidth = 520.0;
  final double baseHeight = 345.0;

  double fromWidth(double size, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return size / baseWidth * constraints.maxWidth;
  }

  double fromHeight(double size, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return size / baseHeight * constraints.maxHeight;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: baseWidth / baseHeight,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 520.0 / 260.0,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    fromWidth(20.0, constraints),
                    fromHeight(40.0, constraints),
                    fromWidth(20.0, constraints),
                    fromHeight(20.0, constraints),
                  ),
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (_, innerConstraints){
                      return Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: PersonDrawer(),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: fromWidth(20.0, constraints),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(0.0, innerConstraints.maxHeight / 2.0),
                              child: PersonDrawer(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: fromWidth(20.0, constraints),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: PersonDrawer(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: fromHeight(20.0, constraints),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 520.0 / 65.0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: fromHeight(16.0, constraints),
                      horizontal: fromWidth(32.0, constraints),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.orange[400],
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.local_florist),
                              Text('x 70 = \$10'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Buy now'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PersonDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white10,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white12),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1.0,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 5.0,
                  right: 5.0,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.camera,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'King_20',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange[400],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 10.0),
                      Text(
                        'ID: 1234567',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: I am unable to set background image(egle)